# 12Factor Explicitly declare and isolate dependencies?

Tags: spring, maven, 12factor

In the 12 factor app. #2 dependencies Explicitly declare and isolate dependencies.
In my pom.xml I have given the version numbers to my dependencies, but I receive

```
Overriding managed version 1.4.2.RELEASE for spring-boot-devtools
Overriding managed version 1.1.1 for json-simple
Overriding managed version 2.8.4 for jackson-annotations
Overriding managed version 4.3.4.RELEASE for spring-oxm
```

When I delete the versions from these dependency the warning label is gone.
Is it safe to remove the versions or ignore them?
If I remove the versions am I still following the 12factor #2 "Explicitly" declare and isolate dependencies.

**POM.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
              <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
               <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
              <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
             <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
             <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
             <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

                <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

                <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>
```

Comment: without your pom file it's hard to say what's going or...

Comment: added pom.xml, removed unaffected dependencies

Comment: So you define the version for spring-oxm as 4.2.4.RELEASE whereas the parent defines it as `4.3.4.RELEASE` which shows you should remove the version which you have given to `spring-oxm` cause the spring parent knows better than you. Also this also applies to the other dependencies...

Comment: Okay, if I remove the versions from those dependencies the versions won't change over time right? The parent basically explicitly provide those dependencies the versions?

Comment: Yes that's the idea behind that to make it more easier to use. If you like to upgrade to new versions upgrade the parent...

Comment: Thank you. Can you create an answer so I can accept and close post.